# Can we update the help center article to indicate that there are more exceptions to the general rule besides the comments only lock?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

The post notice for a Policy Lock has a link to this help center article https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts.

This page states:

> In most cases, a post which is "locked" cannot be modified in any way. Locking prevents...
>
> - ...voting on the post (including close/reopen votes for questions)
> - ...editing
> - ...commenting
> - ...answering (for questions)
> - ...flagging (though "in need of moderator intervention" flags are still allowed, except in the case of Historical Significance locks - see below)
>
> The one exception to this is the "Comments only lock", which only prevents new comments from being added to the question or answer that is locked.

In cases where a Policy Lock is applied the options given in the list aren't true, except for the second item, editing. The sentence below the list notes that there is only one exception to these rules, which is the "Comments only lock". With the introduction of the Policy Lock, this is no longer true.

<strike>**Can the help center article be edited accordingly?**</strike>

As [Spevacus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/622284/spevacus) pointed out, this was requested before in the [original announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/349282/622284) and marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) subsequently. The part that was introduced about the Policy Lock is all the way down the page:

> #### When should a post be locked?
>
> ....... 
> 3. An official policy may sometimes be locked with a special, staff-only lock to prevent editing, closure, and deletion. Moderators can not add or remove this lock and are also subject to its restrictions.

I was thus easily fooled by the first list, and the notice about there being only one exception.

**Can we edit this sentence:**

> The one exception to this is the "Comments only lock", which only prevents new comments from being added to the question or answer that is locked.

**to indicate that there are more exceptions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Help Center page on locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts) (located at `/help/locked-posts` on a site) has now been updated network-wide. As you note, policy locks are already explained later in the page, so I've simply edited the earlier sentence to say "primary exception" instead of "one exception". (I also did some minor copyediting.)