# Should we open up each Stack Exchange policy to discussion by allowing each policy to be made into a question?

Tags: feature-request, policy

Some context - How does and how should site governance work?

I understand that any websites must follow external policy (an example is - don't put underage users at risk of seeing nudity, etc.) and it also follows internal policy (an example is don't undermine the quality of the content on the site).

So there must be policy in place. Furthermore, some policies require proactive action (such as developing a new category or doing site software, configuration or content updates). Some policies require the blocking of action (stopping users from deleting or corrupting valuable content). But policies also need to be themselves updated/negotiated and they also need investigating and debating.

I'm trying to say that I think we should change how legislation on the site is decided and we should open up each policy to debate. If that framework is not in place, I'm just a user with no rights and communities where there are people with no rights are called dictatorships and that is often how I feel Stack Exchange sites are.

If you are happy with this then please downvote this and rile against it, but if you want change let’s discuss it.

I'm often getting flagged and reprimanded for unclear reasons. If we make each policy discussable (into its own question) then moderators can give clear indication as to what the policy breach was and the policy itself can be very easily understood and very well evaluated.

Comment: This is what per-site-metas are for. Please take our [tour] and read the [help], preferably familiarise yourself with the way we work before posting feature requests in particular.

Comment: Where can I find the per site meta on for instance the https://gardening.stackexchange.com forum?

Comment: @TechnoloJesus https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/ Also, Stack Exchange sites are *not* forums.

Comment: Also available from the burger menu top right on any site..

Comment: Could you please advise what you mean by per site meta and where I can find it?

Comment: Every site has its own Meta (the "per site" meta) for discussions about things that only apply to that site. This Meta here is for discussions that apply to all sites. The "list of sites" menu item at the top right of the page always has the link to the site meta as the first item.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmYUA.jpg it's in the SE/hamburger menu on the site you're on at the time

Comment: Well, talk about bait and switch - what started as a reasonable request turned into a rant with accusations of dictatorship and biased assumptions about voting patterns ("if you are happy..."). As mentioned by others, every policy on the network that is in control of the community is open to discussion - but given that behind every policy there is a reasoning, you have to be damn sure of the arguments you make or expect chill reception.

Comment: I think that questions loaded up with assertions without evidence should be downvoted to oblivion.  If you are happy with this then please down-vote this question and rile against it.

Answer (score 11):

> Should we open up each stack exchange policy to discussion by allowing each policy to be made into a QA thread?

It simply isn't possible to make *every* policy open for discussion. Things like at which age underage users are considered underage and how those user accounts are handled for example: There are laws governing that stuff, and having discussions over that is just a fruitless waste of time, as laws won't allow changing the policy (and e.g. keeping the account from an underage user).

More broadly though, most policies are made on (per-site) meta, and are open to discussion. Even posts that are locked with an official [policy-lock](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349276/369802) still accept interactions that would allow discussions, like answers and comments. The only thing here is: Sometimes policies are made and people are well aware of certain downsides, but have decided democratically that those downsides are outweighed by the benefits of having a certain policy. If you go (re-)starting a discussion, be aware of this and make sure you come up with original arguments.

Answer (score -4):

That's what a per-site-meta site is for. To access it, go to

1. "Hamburger menu on right"
2. "current community"
3. "[insert community name here] Meta" (sometime written "meta [insert community name here]")